# Создние toolbar из списка

Tags: python, qt, gui, pyqt5

Допустим у нас есть список вида:

```
[
 [id, name, pixmap]
 [id, name, pixmap]
 ...
]
```

Задача создать toolbar с кнопочками из этого списка.
Сейчас я просто обхожу список и добавляю кнопку, примерно так:

```
for item in items:
    action = QAction(QIcon(item[2]), item[1], actionG, triggered=lambda: print(item[0]))
    toolbar.addAction(action)
```

Я предполагал, что при нажатии кнопки будет выводиться в консоль id каждой кнопки, а выводится только последней.

Вопрос такой: как правильно реализовать возможность вызова функции, допустим print как в примере, чтобы она знала какая конкретно нажата кнопка. При условии что toolbar создается динамически на основании списка.

Comment: А в самом списке действительно id разные? Попробуйте вывести весь items до того, как итерироваться по нему.

Comment: да, id точно разные, они берутся из файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется я разобрался, в чём дело. Попробуйте переписать лямбду вот так:

```
lambda item=item: print(item[0])
```

Comment: вы оказались почти правы. только нужно:
lambda x, item=item[0]: print(item)

в x будет помещено True т.к. сработало нажатие кнопки, а в item уже нужный параметр.